# Summation of dataframes in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sum

I have a list of 10 dataframes. Each dataframe contains 224 rows and 16 columns. I want to create a single dataframe that adds up all the data in 10 dataframe and returns a new datadrame of 224 rows and 16 columns.
I am unable to do it via

```
eu3 <- lapply(eu2, function(x) aggregate(x, sum))
```

The first column is commmon for all dataframes as `Country`. I find that this piece of code `eu3 <- aggregate(. ~ Country, rbind(df1,df2), sum)` works for individual dataframes. Can we put this into use for a list in a function?

Comment: yes, so I think this would work? `aggregate(.~ Country, Reduce(rbind, eu2), sum)`

Comment: If I move Country column as rowname in list then how to aggregate the same with rownames instead of Country?

Comment: It would be better if you keep them as column values instead of rownames because, rownames will not accept duplicate values. So every `Country` would be suffixed with `1` `2` etc and it would be difficult to `aggregate`. However, if you manage to have duplicate rownames you can do `list_df <- Reduce(rbind, eu2)` and then `aggregate(.~rownames(list_df), list_df, sum)`